# assistance with my batch calculator

Tags: batch-file

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my batch script? I just doesn't work...

```
@echo off
:start
echo please enter a mathamatical equation
set /p varia=
set /a %varia%
pause
goto start
```

If you go into command prompt and type in

```
set /a (9*5+4-9)/10
```

the next line is

```
4
```

So my idea is putting it into a batch script and use variables, but no good.  I even tried just

```
set /a 5+5
```

but that failed too.  For some reason the cmd command doesn't work in a batch file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead try this:

```
@echo off
:start
echo Please enter a mathamatical equation: 
set /p varia=
set /a answer=%varia%
echo =%answer%
pause
goto start
```

As you have turned `echo off` the variable's value won't be echoed.

Mona